# Failed to deploy to Azure Web App(my-app) with resource creation or updating, unsupported text Content-Type Type: class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, azure, azure-webapps

I just created Hello World Maven Archetype(`org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp`) application in IntelliJ Idea (following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-intellij/create-hello-world-web-app)
Application do nothing spectacular, just in `index.jsp` I have:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to Deploy to Azure Web App but receive error:

```
Failed to deploy to Azure Web App(my-app) with resource creation or updating, unsupported text Content-Type Type: class java.lang.Object.
```

My Azure Web App has:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just change `Operation system` and `SKU and size`

[image]

and it fixed issue:

```
Deployment succeed but the app is still starting at server side.
```